# Rest at the beginning of a score in musicxml

Tags: musescore, rests, musicxml

I've been studying diverse musicXML files with MuseScore and I've found that usually rest notes are easily represented and visible in its musicXML file.

Yet, I found this 'repeated rest' at the start of a song which has particularly intrigued me since I'm using the xml file to build an object for a different software, resulting into a repeated rest which is obviously not desired.

It has a `backup` value which I couldn't find much information about. I'm obviously not a musician.

The duplicated rest

```
<measure number="1" width="148.52">
      <print>
        ....
        </print>
      <attributes>
        ...
        <staff-details number="1">
          ...
        </attributes>
      <note>
        <rest measure="yes"/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <staff>1</staff>
        </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>8</duration>
        </backup>
      <note>
        <rest measure="yes"/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <staff>2</staff>
        </note>
      </measure>
<measure number="2" width="121.94">
  <note>
    <rest/>
    <duration>2</duration>
    <voice>1</voice>
    <type>quarter</type>
    <staff>1</staff>
    </note>
  <note default-x="42.79" default-y="-30.00">
    <pitch>
      <step>E</step>
      <octave>4</octave>
```

The partiture:

[image: Fragment of a score. Treble clef, key signature with one sharp, 4/4 time, the first measure is a whole measure rest, the second measure is a quarter rest followed by three notes with down-bow marks.]

What also calls my attention is that the rest note does not have any `type` value which according to the `museScore` partiture it should be a half.

Next rest, which is also a rest, has its proper value of a `quarter` and it's not repeated.

It's important to understand this, otherwise I will not be able to generate the proper algorithm for the time stamps of each note.

The complete start of the musicxml file if case you find it useful

```
<part id="P2">
    <measure number="1" width="148.52">
      <print>
        <staff-layout number="1">
          <staff-distance>0.00</staff-distance>
          </staff-layout>
        <staff-layout number="2">
          <staff-distance>76.96</staff-distance>
          </staff-layout>
        </print>
      <attributes>
        <divisions>2</divisions>
        <key>
          <fifths>1</fifths>
          </key>
        <time>
          <beats>4</beats>
          <beat-type>4</beat-type>
          </time>
        <staves>2</staves>
        <clef number="1">
          <sign>TAB</sign>
          <line>5</line>
          </clef>
        <clef number="2">
          <sign>G</sign>
          <line>2</line>
          </clef>
        <staff-details number="1">
          <staff-lines>4</staff-lines>
          <staff-tuning line="1">
            <tuning-step>G</tuning-step>
            <tuning-octave>3</tuning-octave>
            </staff-tuning>
          <staff-tuning line="2">
            <tuning-step>D</tuning-step>
            <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
            </staff-tuning>
          <staff-tuning line="3">
            <tuning-step>A</tuning-step>
            <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
            </staff-tuning>
          <staff-tuning line="4">
            <tuning-step>E</tuning-step>
            <tuning-octave>5</tuning-octave>
            </staff-tuning>
          </staff-details>
        </attributes>
      <note>
        <rest measure="yes"/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <staff>1</staff>
        </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>8</duration>
        </backup>
      <note>
        <rest measure="yes"/>
        <duration>8</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <staff>2</staff>
        </note>
      </measure>
    <measure number="2" width="121.94">
      <note>
        <rest/>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <staff>1</staff>
        </note>
      <note default-x="42.79" default-y="-30.00">
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>down</stem>
        <staff>1</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            <string>3</string>
            <fret>2</fret>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      <note default-x="69.64" default-y="-30.00">
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>down</stem>
        <staff>1</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            <string>3</string>
            <fret>2</fret>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      <note default-x="96.49" default-y="-15.00">
        <pitch>
          <step>B</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>1</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>down</stem>
        <staff>1</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            <string>2</string>
            <fret>2</fret>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      <backup>
        <duration>8</duration>
        </backup>
      <note>
        <rest/>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <staff>2</staff>
        </note>
      <note default-x="39.79" default-y="-161.96">
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>up</stem>
        <staff>2</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      <note default-x="66.64" default-y="-161.96">
        <pitch>
          <step>E</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>up</stem>
        <staff>2</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      <note default-x="93.49" default-y="-141.96">
        <pitch>
          <step>B</step>
          <octave>4</octave>
          </pitch>
        <duration>2</duration>
        <voice>5</voice>
        <type>quarter</type>
        <stem>down</stem>
        <staff>2</staff>
        <notations>
          <technical>
            <down-bow/>
            </technical>
          </notations>
        </note>
      </measure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what was that `backup` about, despite finding some shallow information ([here](https://usermanuals.musicxml.com/MusicXML/Content/CT-MusicXML-backup.htm)), however found nothing that could help me that much.

In the end, and after visiting several other songs, I just ignored any `rest` note that didn't have a `staff` value of `1`, thus I was able to map perfectly the song.